# SQL update records compared to records from another table

Tags: sql, sql-update

Should be fairly simple.

I have 2 tables. One of them has table1(ID,name,other_id) and the other table has table2(id,name,group,..)

I want table1.other_id to be same as table2.id based on the data in the name fields on both tables.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What flavour sql are you using? SQL Server? mySQL?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.other_id = t2.id
FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
```

This is of course assuming you don't have multiple records with the same "name", otherwise how would you tell which record with a given name you want the ID for from table2.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
update table1 t1
set other_id = (
    select id
    from table2 t2
    where t2.name = t1.name )
```

This will fail if `table2` has multiple records with the same name.